# How do I install Cake (the C# build automation system) on 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, cake

I would like to install Cake on 16.04, but how do I? I know that Cake has no packages in the official Xenial repositories (which I know by running `sudo apt-cache search cake`). Cake also does not seem to exist in any unofficial repositories for Ubuntu as I have Google searched for this. I know that two zip archives are released for each Cake release on GitHub (see https://github.com/cake-build/cake/releases for details), but how am I meant to install these archives?

Answer (score 0):

Cake is just .net (mono) tool for build automation - scripting, so it sits on top of .net scripting system (*.csx files).

We (Xamarin Components Team) is using it on our Macs and Windows to build our Components. I personally use it on Linux too.

Linux per se cannot run .net/mono binaries, so you need to launch CLR - common language runtime (.net runtime, like java JVM). So:

```
mono tools/Cake/Cake.exe --verbosity=diagnostic --target=libs
```

On windows you do not need mono executable to be specified.

In the future with .net core:

```
dotnet tools/Cake/Cake.exe --verbosity=diagnostic --target=libs
```

Installation:

Most of new .net tools try to follow web script installation pattern, download script and run it which can be oneliner (like brew on Mac), so for linux:

```
    curl -Lsfo build.sh http://cakebuild.net/download/bootstrapper/linux
    chmod +x ./build.sh && ./build.sh
```

It is installed in your current directory in tools/ folder. It downloads minimal runtime, Roslyn compiler, nuget package managers and else what you need. This is the reason there is no need for package.